# Ioinc 3 - Sqlite insert response.json() and retrieve

Tags: json, database, sqlite, ionic3

In Ionic 3 mobile application, is that possible to store the `response.json()` values in to sqlite database and while retrieving we can parse and convert in to objects?

### Sample code

```
this.service.getEmployeeDtls().subscribe((response) => {
      if (response.status == 200) {
        let empDtls= response.json();
        // want to store the empDtls to sqlite database as it is
      }
```

If is this not possible then only way is we have to parse JSON values and insert one by one in to database.

Comment: Why not use Ionic Storage?

Comment: You store data using ionic storage or localForage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution and it is fine to store the data in SQLite database.

```
var city:City = new City(response.json());
```

create a modal class and get assign to that.

```
export class City {
cityId: numbner;
cityName: string;
 constructor(json?: any) {
        if (json) {
            Object.assign(this, json);
        }
 }

 getCityId() {
}
 setCityId() {
}

 getCityName() {
}
 setCityName() {
}
....
}

}
```

then we can create a table and insert the values like

**city.cityId, city.cityName**

in the SQLite database. It is working fine.

Thanks

Comment: explain please because it's confusing